# DDLogCVerbose vs. DDLogVerbose

Tags: objective-c, logging, cocoalumberjack

What are differences between DDLog(Error|Warn|Info|Verbose) and DDLogC(Error|Warn|Info|Verbose) in Cocoa Lumberjack?

The first calls LOG_OBJC_MAYBE, second LOG_C_MAYBE, but what is the exact difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wondering the same thing until I tried to use `DDLog` in one of my "C" function.
The `DDLog` macro retrieves the name of the Objective C method with `_cmd` which is not available for C functions.
For C functions `DDLogC` uses `__FUNCTION__` to retrieve the name.
Conclusion `DDLog` is to be used in Objective C methods and `DDLogC` in C functions.

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation states, DDLog(Error|Warn|Info|Verbose) is used for objective C code and DDLogC(Error|Warn|Info|Verbose) is used for C code. Please stick to th